# How to make DynamicSelect() work with a basic tank example?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, graphical-interaction

I try to make animation work with use of Dynamic Select() in the annotation.
The examples provided in Mechanics/Multibody/Examples/Elementary/DoublePendulum works fine for me using OM 1.21 and MSL 3.2.3.

Now I try my own code with just a pump that pumps liquid into to a tank of mine
and I want the liquid level increase with the increase volume pumped into the tank.

[image]

The harvestTank5 icon is a rectangle with a rectangle inside with FillPattern.Solid.
The annotation is as follows and I have entered the function DynamicSelect(),
but here just repeated the first argument into the second. The simulation works.

[image]

If I now change the last argument in DynamicSelecdt to  {40, V}, where V is a real variable that represent the dynamically changing liquid volume, then I after
translation just get a big square icon where harvesttank5 is now. The simulation
stil works, but I do not get any animation results.

I think I follow the example with MSL Fluid/Media with tanks very well
but it does not work.

See https://www.claytex.com/blog/using-dynamicselect-in-icons/

Comment: I don't think we support DynamicSelect like that, meaning that it returns the entire extent, you can try to do extent = {{-40, 40}, DynamicSelect({40, -40}, {40, V})} instead

Comment: This should work with the instance API. Makesure you have instance API enabled. Check `Tools->Options->Enable instance API` and restart OMEdit.

Comment: Tried first Adeel's idea, and I needed to do the enable instance API with restart, but then got bigger boxes around feedTank, pump, and harvestTank5, i.e. components that include liquid phase. The electrical component giving a constant signal to the pump was un-affected.  Simulations ok, but no animation effect. Perhaps more basic things to "switch on"? I then tried Adrians idea with the API switched on and got no changes. Does this have anything to do with MSL 3.2.3 or 4.0.0?

Comment: Seems like a bug. Please open a ticket with a minimal test model https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/new/choose

Comment: Ok, give me a day or two and I will create a minimal test model for you.